# Element does not retain its Storyboard accessibility identifier or type in runtime

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode-ui-testing

I have an automated UI test to make sure a page displays the correct elements by searching for them using XCUIElement queries like so

```
let instructionLabelID = "UIA_HelpViewController_InstructionLabel"
let callViewID = "UIA_HelpViewController_CallTextView"

var instructionLabel: XCUIElement { return app.staticTexts[instructionLabelID] }
var instructions: String { return instructionLabel.label }

var callLabel: XCUIElement { return app.textViews[callViewID] }
var callText: String { return callLabel.value as! String }
```

Here is the corresponding storyboard

[image: storyboard]

The test fails due to the highlighted view not being found, even though we can see its identifier is correct in the storyboard. With a breakpoint I can check all the elements during runtime, and here is the result

[image: bp]

As we can see, the first element is correct in that it is under an Other (its container view), has type StaticText, and has its identifier. The second element however seems to be merged into its container rather than being a child of it. Both containers have the Accessibility Enabled option unchecked. How can I fix this?

Comment: I also have this IB Designables build error, though everything still runs so I'm not sure if it's related - file:///Users/jason/company-ios-module-module/Pods/CoShared/Resources/iOS/Storyboards/QA.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for HelpViewController (bf9-4a-BGY): dlopen(CoShared.framework, 1): image not found

Comment: It looks like you have set the text view to have accessibilityTraits = .notEnabled on the container rather than setting isAccessibilityElement = false, can you confirm how you disabled accessibility?

Comment: Can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it? I was setting the accessibility via storyboard. Going in the corresponding swift file and setting it via code led to me discovering an extension that was hardcoding isAccessibilityElement to true, which is why it ignored anything I did to disable it

Comment: Answered and adjusted to include what you found so this might help others with the same problem who find this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have set the text view to have accessibilityTraits = .notEnabled on the container rather than setting isAccessibilityElement = false.

Try to set these properties in code rather than in the storyboard if possible as it gives you more control - storyboard values can easily be overwritten but if you set it up in code, you can control when the identifiers are set and override them if there is any interference.

Comment: A search for the container's outlet variable name revealed the culprit. Thank you!